# Determine the value of (p,q)?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

find all value of $(p,q)$ for  which integral

$$\int_0^1 x^p\ln^q(1/x)dx$$

converges ?

## My answer is $p > q-1$

Is It correct?

Proof : $$\int_0^1 x^p\ln^q(1/x)dx\le\int_0^1x^{p-q}dx= \frac{1}{p-q+1}$$

Comment: What about other cases? You clearly have not found *all* values.

Comment: As $$\int_{0}^{1}x\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\text{d}x=\frac{1}{4}$$ your answer seems to be incomplete (it's only one of many examples which do not follow the condition you have found).

Comment: @xbh   then  what is  the answer ?

Comment: @Galc127  okkss but  u have take $p=q=1$

Comment: @jasmine, Oops, my bad... you can take $p=0,q=1$ and you have $$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\text{d}x=1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
Let $\ln\dfrac1x=u$ then
$$I=\int_0^\infty u^qe^{-(p+1)u}\ du$$
which may expressed as gamma function.

Comment: sir  is there any other method??  as   i didn't study  gamma function .

Comment: @jasmine Then how about directly testing the convergence for Gamma function?

Comment: @xbh then  what is the correct answer , i need answer ????

Comment: @jasmine We have $\ln\alpha<\alpha-1$ then
$$I<\int_0^1x^{p-q}(1-x)^{q}\ dx<\int_0^1(1-x)^{q}\ dx=\int_0^1x^q\ dx<\infty$$
if $1+q>0$.

Comment: thanks u sir @Nosrati